# How to get the ajax response from success and assign it in a variable using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hello guys I have a problem in getting the response from my ajax. If I display it in the console. I can view it. But How do I assign it in a variable?

Here's what I have.
In my PHP code I have this

```
public function checkPassword($password){

            $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
            $validate = $this->members_model->checkPassword($password,$username);

            echo $validate;

}
```

In my jquery I have this

```
$('#existing').on('keyup',function(){

            var id = '<?php echo $this->session->userdata("user_id"); ?>';
            var password_url = '<?php echo site_url("member/checkPassword/' +id+ '"); ?>';

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: password_url,
                data: '',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){

                var g = response;
                if(g == 1){
                    $('#existing_info').html('Password is VALID'); //Doesn't display the VALID if the response is 1. Why?
                }else{
                    $('#existing_info').html('Password is INVALID!');
                }

                }

            });

        });
```

Comment: use `window.k = response`

Comment: @rab are you sure that bumping a variable to global scope is a good way to access it later? How would you know it's been set? It's being set by a click event that may or may not happen after an asynch request.

Comment: post the json response

Comment: Actually it is not a json. The response is 1 or 0 only.

Comment: @Jerielle Try adding content type as json . See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393093/how-to-get-the-ajax-response-from-success-and-assign-it-in-a-variable-using-jque/20393114#20393114

Comment: If you don't want to return json, then remove both dataType and contentType. Otherwise jQuery will try to parse object from json.

Comment: Also you will  be getting a string as response, but you are comparing with a numeric. try `g == '1'` instead `g == 1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: password_url,
        data: '',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
           var k=response;

           if(k.indexOf("1") != -1)
             $('#existing_info').html('Password is VALID');
           else
              $('#existing_info').html('Password is INVALID!');
        }
    });
```

`response` is in response variable of success function.

**[indexof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)** returns the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at fromIndex,
**returns -1 if the value is not found**.

Comment: Same output. The console output is correct but it doesn't display the correct message. If 1 display VALID if 0 display INVALID. But whether the response is 1 or 0. I always end up with INVALID

Comment: Ok it works thanks. I still confused with the code your code. But thank you very much for the right answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

try something like this

```
   <script>
        var k = null;
        $(function(){
            $('#existing').on('keyup',function(){
                var id = '<?php echo $this->session->userdata("user_id"); ?>';
                var password_url = '<?php echo site_url("member/checkPassword/' +id+ '"); ?>';

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: password_url,
                    data: '',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response){
                        if(response == 1){
                            k = response;
                        }
                    }

                });

            });
        })
   </script>
```

Comment: Ok I am creating a validation that simple output 'VALID' or 'INVALID' in the console. But If the response is in '1'. It doesn't display the 'VALID' in console

Answer (score 2):

In your success response you will get what you are set to output in php.
If you want to get an array or data set you can encode it in json in your php script like

```
echo json_encode($validate);
```

Then in your jquery you can use this response like this

```
var responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
console.log(responseData);
```

console.log will print json object in browser console.
You can use this json object like this

```
responseData.some_data
```

Comment: I don't think so that use json_encode for single output from the php script, we can simply echo data.

Comment: I already explained that if you want to use array or a data set.

Answer (score 2):

Ajax is asynch so you will have access to it after the ajax method returns:

```
$('#existing').on('keyup',function(){

            var id = '<?php echo $this->session->userdata("user_id"); ?>';
            var password_url = '<?php echo site_url("member/checkPassword/' +id+ '"); ?>';

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: password_url,
                data: '',
                dataType: 'json'
            }).then(function(response){
              var k;
              if(response == 1){
                k = response;
                //call another function that needs k here
              }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: password_url,
            data: '',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){

               k=response;

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your response data is in `response` variable of success function. Since the response type is json you can assign it directly to javaScript variable.

Also you comparison is wrong try `if(g == '1')` instead `if(g == 1)`. You are getting a string as response and your checking equality with a numeric type which won't be equal at any point.

ie:-

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: password_url,
                data: '',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType:"application/json",// Add Content type too
                success: function(response){
                    k=response;
                  }
        });
```

if your json response is as shown below

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

you can access menuitem array as

```
success: function(response){
               k=response.menu.popup.menuitem;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

response parameter itself contain data so just assign that to variable and use it.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: password_url,
        success: function(response){
         if(parseInt(response) == 1){ 
          var k = response;
          }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I updated the code. But I can't get the correct response if the response is 1.

Comment: You can check the value before assign to that a variable. console or alert that response.

Comment: Hey that was my mistake I defined data type json for response just remove that one it will work.

Comment: Same output. The console output is correct but it doesn't display the correct message. If 1 display VALID if 0 display INVALID. But whether the response is 1 or 0. I always end up with INVALID

Comment: I think there is problem in comparison. your are comparing response with integer value so before it parse response with integer. I have updated my answer use that.

Comment: @jerielle Please provide your feedback. did my answer work for you or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
var k = null;

$('#existing').on('keyup', function() {
  var id           = '<?php echo $this->session->userdata("user_id"); ?>',
      password_url = '<?php echo site_url("member/checkPassword/' +id+ '"); ?>';

  $.ajax({
    type    : 'POST',
    url     : password_url,
    success : function(data) {
      if(data === '1') {
        k = data;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

File Name votepost.php

```
<?php
include("domain.php");

$csid=$_POST['CSID'];
$voteid=$_POST['VOTEID'];
$myid=$_POST['MYID'];
$usertype=$_POST['USERTYPE'];


$myurl =URL."putvote.php?csid=".$csid."&voterid=".$myid."&voteid=".$voteid."&usertype=".$usertype;
$myurl=str_replace(" ","%20",$myurl);
$jsondata = file_get_contents($myurl);
$data = json_decode($jsondata);

if($data->response=="true")
{
    echo 'true';

}
else
{
    echo 'false';

}


?>
```

ajax reponse use $.trim for IF ELSE

```
$.post("votepost.php", {CSID:csid,VOTEID:voteid,MYID:myid,USERTYPE:usertype}, function (data) {

        if($.trim(data)=='true')
        {
            alert('ok');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
```

I hope you will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can create the js blank array and assign it to the same array.

```
var resp = [];
    jQuery.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            method: 'post',
            url: 'ajax.php',
            async: false,
            data: {postData: 'postData'},
            success: function(data){
                resp.push(data);
            }
    });
```