# Using variable from ajax response as json

Tags: jquery, mysql, json, ajax, c3.js

Im still newbie from ajax and Jquery, I will show my data base in graphic using c3.js, but I cant use my ajax response to javascript variable. This is my JSON response from response.php

```
[{"time":"2014-05-20 17:25:00","sensor1":"25","sensor2":"20","sensor3":"31","sensor4":"33","sensor5":"27"},{"time":"2014-05-20 17:26:00","sensor1":"26","sensor2":"23","sensor3":"33","sensor4":"31","sensor5":"23"}]
```

and this is my response.php

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "perkebunan";

//Connect to MySQL Server
$server = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

//Select Database
mysql_select_db($dbname, $server) or die(mysql_error());
//build query
$query = "SELECT * FROM sensor";    
//Execute query
$qry_result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$results = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry_result))
{
    $temp = array(
        'time' => $row['time'],
        'sensor1' => $row['sensor1'],
        'sensor2' => $row['sensor2'],
        'sensor3' => $row['sensor3'],
        'sensor4' => $row['sensor4'],
        'sensor5' => $row['sensor5']
    );
    array_push($results,$temp);
}
echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

and this is my database

[my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB54R.png)

so please help me to make my json response to varible in javascript. this my trial index.php to make it posible.

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Load c3.css -->
    <link href="c3/c3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Load d3.js and c3.js -->
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="c3/c3.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
function graphAjax(){
    var response;
     $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'ajax-example.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: { },
        success: function(data){
            response=data;
        }
    });
    var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
        json: {response
            /* I hope this variable response give result like this
            time: [2014-05-20 17:25:00, 2014-05-20 17:26:00, 2014-05-20 17:27:00, 2014-05-20 17:28:00, 2014-05-20 17:29:00],
            sensor1: [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
            sensor2: [20, 23, 22, 25, 28],
            sensor3: [31, 33, 35, 30, 33],
            sensor4: [33, 31, 28, 25, 27],
            sensor5: [27, 23, 21, 19, 18],
            */
        }
    }
    });
}
</script>

   <input type='button' onclick='graphAjax()' value='Start'/>
</body>
<footer>
</footer>
</html>
```

thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since AJAX works asyncronously you need some kind of work-around. For instance, you can move the function that generates your chart inside the `success` callback function (and define what happens in case of an error adding

```
success: function(data){
            response=data;
            // generate chart here
        },
 error: function () {
            // do something
        },
```

Check also [this extensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/2314737) to [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)) or [How to get the ajax response from success and assign it in a variable using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393093/how-to-get-the-ajax-response-from-success-and-assign-it-in-a-variable-using-jque).

Comment: finally, thanks for your help, now my graph is appear